# How to know if the user is Already SignedIn and thus prevent displaying the Login page in asp dot net core 2.0 Cookie based authentication?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

This is the basic code snippet !!
Show me the Login page if none of the user is signedIn. If any user is active it should redirect to Index Page of Home Controller and should not show Login page !!

```
public class AccountController : CommonController
   {
    public AccountController(IOptions<ConnectionSetting> connString) : base(connString)
    {

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {            
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(User user)
    {
        if (ValidateUser(user.UserName , user.Password))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name , user.UserName)
            };

            //Now Create an ClaimIdentity
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "BloggingCookie");

            //Create Claim Principal using that Identity
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);                

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("BloggingCookie", principal );

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Status"] = "Invalid Username or Password";
            return View();
        }

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to add something like the following to the top of your login action:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
}
```

You can of course redirect to wherever you like.